# How to create a pandas density plot with datetime.date on the x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, axis, kernel-density

```
#dataframe
a=
timestamp      count
2021-08-16     20
2021-08-17     60
2021-08-18     35
2021-08-19      1
2021-08-20      0
2021-08-21      1
2021-08-22     50
2021-08-23     36
2021-08-24     68
2021-08-25    125
2021-08-26     54


I applied this code
a.plot(kind="density")
```

this is not what i want.
[image: plot]

I want to put `Count` on Y axis and `timestamp` in X axis with Density plotting.

just like i can do it with `plt.bar(a['timestamp'],a['count'])`

OR this is not possible with Density plotting?

Comment: for pandas 1.1.0 or newer, you can set `xlabel` and `ylabel` in the plotting command

Comment: @Stef  plotting is also different here. i want time stamp on X and Count on Y.  which i cant get here

Comment: Do you want both the densitiy plot and the bar plot have in the same chart? It's possible with it doesn't seem to make much sense to me. I thinks it's better to make two charts.

Comment: ok. is it possible to do with a Histogram? @Stef

Comment: like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyZsY.png)?

Comment: yes, (if possible)but i want Timestamp on X axis, and Count on Y axis. that's why i am struggling @Stef

Comment: But then it's not a histogram but a bar chart. I don't think it helps readability to combine the density plot and the bar plot (no matter what's on the x and what's on the y axis) in one chart.

Comment: yes, so the thing i want is not possible with histogram?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code creates a density histogram. The total area sums to 1, supposing each of the timestamps counts as 1 unit. To get the timestamps as x-axis, they are set as the index.  To get the total area to sum to 1, all count values are divided by their total sum.

A kde a calculated from the same data.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
from io import StringIO

a_str = '''timestamp      count
2021-08-16     20
2021-08-17     60
2021-08-18     35
2021-08-19      1
2021-08-20      0
2021-08-21      1
2021-08-22     50
2021-08-23     36
2021-08-24     68
2021-08-25    125
2021-08-26     54'''
a = pd.read_csv(StringIO(a_str), delim_whitespace=True)

ax = (a.set_index('timestamp') / a['count'].sum()).plot.bar(width=0.9, rot=0, figsize=(12, 5))

kde = gaussian_kde(np.arange(len(a)), bw_method=0.2, weights=a['count'])

xs = np.linspace(-1, len(a), 200)
ax.plot(xs, kde(xs), lw=2, color='crimson', label='kde')
ax.set_xlim(xs[0], xs[-1])
ax.legend(labels=['kde', 'density histogram'])
ax.set_xlabel('')
ax.set_ylabel('density')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: density histogram from counts]

If you just want to plot the kde curve, you can leave out the histogram. Optionally you can fill the area under the curve.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5))

kde = gaussian_kde(np.arange(len(a)), bw_method=0.2, weights=a['count'])

xs = np.linspace(-1, len(a), 200)
# plot the kde curve
ax.plot(xs, kde(xs), lw=2, color='crimson', label='kernel density estimation')
# optionally fill the area below the curve
ax.fill_between(xs, kde(xs), color='crimson', alpha=0.2)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(a)))
ax.set_xticklabels(a['timestamp'])
ax.set_xlim(xs[0], xs[-1])
ax.set_ylim(ymin=0)
ax.legend()
ax.set_xlabel('')
ax.set_ylabel('density')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: density plot]

To plot multiple similar curves, for example using more `count` columns, you can use a loop. A list of colors that go well together could be obtained from the Set2 colormap:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

a = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': ['2021-08-16', '2021-08-17', '2021-08-18', '2021-08-19', '2021-08-20', '2021-08-21',
                                '2021-08-22', '2021-08-23', '2021-08-24', '2021-08-25', '2021-08-26']})
for i in range(1, 5):
    a[f'count{i}'] = (np.random.uniform(0, 12, len(a)) ** 2).astype(int)

xs = np.linspace(-1, len(a), 200)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
for column, color in zip(a.columns[1:], plt.cm.Set2.colors):
    kde = gaussian_kde(np.arange(len(a)), bw_method=0.2, weights=a[column])
    ax.plot(xs, kde(xs), lw=2, color=color, label=f"kde of '{column}'")
    ax.fill_between(xs, kde(xs), color=color, alpha=0.2)
    ax.set_xlim(xs[0], xs[-1])
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(a)))
ax.set_xticklabels(a['timestamp'])
ax.set_xlim(xs[0], xs[-1])
ax.set_ylim(ymin=0)
ax.legend()
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Density of Counts')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: multiple kde plots]

Comment: hello, thanks for this. but `a` is Dataframe not string. i did not mention it before. sorry for this. does this code work for it?

Comment: can we just get "Red density line"? is it possible?

Comment: In the example code `a` clearly is a dataframe (`a_str` is your string to be converted via `pd.read_csv(....)`). Did you run the example code?

Comment: IT WORKS, thanks alot. can you please tell me which values are stored here to make visualization in UI?

Comment: `kde` is a function that is calculated from the counts.  `xs` is a detailed array to represent the x-axis of the curve.  The curve itself is `kde(xs)`.

Comment: Hello, is it possible to put the Labels on Axis (E,g x-> DATE, y-> Density of Counts )?

Comment: `ax.set_xlabel('DATE'); ax.set_ylabel('Density of Counts')`.  Personality, I wouldn't put that label on the x-axis because from the values themselves it is clear that they are dates.

Comment: @JohanC hello, can you take a look here-: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71020298/can-we-do-denisty-plotting-with-timestamp-in-python