# can we do Denisty plotting with timestamp in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

My question is somewhat similar to this-: [how to put label in dataframe in Density plotting in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70972793/how-to-put-label-in-dataframe-in-density-plotting-in-matplotlib/70974159?noredirect=1#comment125500960_70974159)

because of this I am not putting a code because it is almost same.

but Here I want to do as you can see in the picture.[image: like this]

let me interpret further more.
first this is the data we can take.

```
a_str = '''
timestamp      count
2021-08-16     20
2021-08-17     60
2021-08-18     35
2021-08-19      1
2021-08-20      0
2021-08-21      1
2021-08-22     50
2021-08-23     36
2021-08-24     68
2021-08-25    125
2021-08-26     54'''

a_str1 = '''
timestamp      count
2021-07-16     20
2021-07-17     60
2021-07-18     35
2021-07-19      1
2021-07-20      0
2021-07-21      1
2021-07-22     50
2021-07-23     36
2021-07-24     68
2021-07-25    125
2021-07-26     54'''

a_str2 = '''
timestamp      count
2021-06-16     20
2021-06-17     60
2021-06-18     35
2021-06-19      1
2021-06-20      0
2021-06-21      1
2021-06-22     50
2021-06-23     36
2021-06-24     68
2021-06-25    125
2021-06-26     54'''
```

As we know that Density graph gives info about (density of each values (X axis-: values, Y axis-: actual value))
like this one [image: this is just an exaple]

## what I want

(Plotting does not has to be what i posted above, it is just for the idea of What i want to do)

1. On the X there are actual value of count
2. want to plot "density" of it
3. y axis is a month

before all, is it even possible like this? because i am using density plot so it might not be possible with that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to use the timestamps only for indicating the month? And then create kdeplots using the counts belonging to each month? (The linked question, on the other hand, uses the counts as weights for the individual days)

Comment: @JohanC Thanks for looking at this. yes, it is correct. but count on X axis and "plot density graph". `count` values always in between (10 to 20). here i just put example thats why its random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code draws kde curves at y-values 0,1,2,...  Depending on your concrete situation, you might want to fine-tune some of the constants.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import to_rgb
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

a1 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': pd.date_range('20210816', periods=11),
                   'count': np.random.randint(10, 21, 11)})
a2 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': pd.date_range('20210716', periods=11),
                   'count': np.random.randint(10, 21, 11)})
a3 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': pd.date_range('20210616', periods=11),
                   'count': np.random.randint(10, 21, 11)})
month_counts = [df['count'].values for df in [a1, a2, a3]]
month_names = ['August', 'July', 'June']

max_count = max([count_i.max() for count_i in month_counts])
min_count = min([count_i.min() for count_i in month_counts])
xs = np.linspace(min_count - 3, max_count + 3, 200)
month_kde = [gaussian_kde(count_i, bw_method=0.2) for count_i in month_counts]
max_kde = max([kde_i(xs).max() for kde_i in month_kde])
overlap_factor = 1.9
whiten_factor = 0.5

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
for index, color in zip(range(len(month_names) - 1, -1, -1), np.tile(plt.cm.Set2.colors, (3, 1))):
    kde = month_kde[index](xs) / max_kde * overlap_factor
    ax.plot(xs, index + kde, lw=2, color=color, zorder=50 - index)
    whitened = np.array(to_rgb(color)) * (1 - whiten_factor) + whiten_factor
    ax.fill_between(xs, index, index + kde, color=whitened, alpha=0.8, zorder=50 - index)
ax.set_xlim(xs[0], xs[-1])
ax.set_xlabel('Distribution of Counts')
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(month_names)))
ax.set_yticklabels(month_names)
for spine in ('top', 'left', 'right'):
    ax.spines[spine].set(visible=False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: kde curves for multiple months]

Here is a variation using the `magma` color map as gradient:

```py
month_names = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
               'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
month_counts = [np.random.randint(15 - abs(k - 6), 30 - abs(k - 6), 30) for k in range(len(month_names))]

max_count = max([count_i.max() for count_i in month_counts])
min_count = min([count_i.min() for count_i in month_counts])
xs = np.linspace(min_count - 3, max_count + 3, 200)
month_kde = [gaussian_kde(count_i, bw_method=0.2) for count_i in month_counts]
max_kde = max([kde_i(xs).max() for kde_i in month_kde])
overlap_factor = 1.9

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
for index in range(len(month_names)):
    kde = month_kde[::-1][index](xs) / max_kde * overlap_factor
    ax.plot(xs, index + kde, lw=2, color='black', zorder=50 - 2 * index + 1)
    fill_poly = ax.fill_between(xs, index, index + kde, color='none', alpha=0.8)

    verts = np.vstack([p.vertices for p in fill_poly.get_paths()])
    gradient = ax.imshow(np.linspace(0, 1, 256).reshape(1, -1), cmap='magma', aspect='auto', zorder=50 - 2 * index,
                         extent=[verts[:, 0].min(), verts[:, 0].max(), verts[:, 1].min(), verts[:, 1].max()])
    gradient.set_clip_path(fill_poly.get_paths()[0], transform=plt.gca().transData)

ax.set_xlim(xs[0], xs[-1])
ax.set_ylim(ymin=-0.2)

ax.set_xlabel('Distribution of Counts')
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(month_names)))
ax.set_yticklabels(month_names[::-1])
for spine in ('top', 'left', 'right'):
    ax.spines[spine].set(visible=False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: kde curves for 12 months, using magma color map as gradient]

Comment: Hello, thank you very much. My use case is solved. one more thing just for curiosity, if size of a{1,2,3} is not same or values are not in the bound(10 to 20). it will also work in this case? Again thank you for this!

Comment: Yes, it also works for different sizes. That's why the example uses a list (and not one big numpy array) to represent `month_counts`.  A numpy array would need equal sizes for the sub-arrays.

Comment: hello, i get this error `ValueError: object arrays are not supported`. when i pass three data frame. df1 has 513 values (between 0 to -20) Month is august, df2 has 405 values (between 0 to -10) Month is July  ,df3 has 300 values(0 to -5) Month is July. could you help me with that. "in this Dataframes its time stamp not a Date", maybe i made a mistake here. Could you tell me how to handle this.  it is also of if i just able to plot Df1.

Comment: Are you using it like `[df['count'].values for df in [a1, a2, a3]]`?  Are you sure the values are numbers? (Try `print(a['count'].dtype)` to find out the type).